# Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Peer certificate CN, Failed to enable crypto, I/O warning, failed to open stream,

Tags: apache, openssl, php-7

In Wordpress php5, everything is fine

now with PHP7 I am getting these warnings:

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Peer certificate CN=`getalongwithgod.com' did not match expected CN=`www.readmk.com' in /home/readmk11/staging/1/wp-content/themes/Shulamite/includes/readmk-feed.php on line 21

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Failed to enable crypto in /home/readmk11/staging/1/wp-content/themes/Shulamite/includes/readmk-feed.php on line 21

Warning: DOMDocument::load(https://www.readmk.com/devotionals/feed): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/readmk11/staging/1/wp-content/themes/Shulamite/includes/readmk-feed.php on line 21

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://www.readmk.com/devotionals/feed" in /home/readmk11/staging/1/wp-content/themes/Shulamite/includes/readmk-feed.php on line 21

my class-wp-http-streams.php
says this:

```
$context = stream_context_create( array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => $ssl_verify,
            //'CN_match' => $arrURL['host'], // This is handled by self::verify_ssl_certificate()
            'capture_peer_cert' => $ssl_verify,
            'SNI_enabled' => true,
            'cafile' => $r['sslcertificates'],
            'allow_self_signed' => ! $ssl_verify,
        )
    ) );
```

ALSO, my class-wp-http-curl.php
says this:

/*
         * CURLOPT_TIMEOUT and CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT expect integers. Have to use ceil since.
         * a value of 0 will allow an unlimited timeout.
         */
        $timeout = (int) ceil( $r['timeout'] );
        curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
        curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );

```
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, ( $ssl_verify === true ) ? 2 : false );
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, $ssl_verify );

    if ( $ssl_verify ) {
        curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $r['sslcertificates'] );
    }

    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $r['user-agent'] );
```

I am getting four errors on the site where I think these codes are affecting:

Does anyone know what needs to be changed to my code to make these Warnings go away and the site grab information again in PHP7?

Comment: This is an issue with the certificate on getalongwithgod.com. Try running it through an SSL certificate checker (like the one from SSL Labs). Your PHP version upgrade may be a red herring.

Comment: Thank you so much John! If it’s not too much trouble, Can you explain how I might do that? That’s a wordpress site as well.

Comment: Sure. I was slightly incorrect; the certificate for readmk.com is not valid for that domain. [Here's some test results](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=readmk.com&latest). It looks like it's serving a certificate for getalongwithgod.com, not readmk.com.

Comment: thanks John! Very appreciated! I’ll check into that!